# cancel an existing alertdialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hi i am writing a program which show an alertdialog every 15 minutes using an alarmmanager.But when doing this the  alertdialogs were placed  above the other. I had used isshowing() but not worked .This is my code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Check new files  ");
    builder.setNegativeButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();
            }
  });

AlertDialog  alert=builder.create();
    if(alert.isShowing()){
        alert.dismiss();
    }
    else{
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: dismiss it before creating new

Comment: you are creating the new object and checking if it is visible.but new object will always return false  in isShowing

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the new object every time and checking if it is visible.but new object will always return false in isShowing()

if u want to use isshowing() then use that old object of that alert dailog

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `boolean isActive` global. Initialize it as `false`, and if the dialog is created set it to `true`. 
Now you can ask:

```
if (isActive) {
    alert.dismiss(); 
} else { 
    alert.show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare Boolean isactive = false; globally and set true when you are adding alert and and set false when removing alert replace this code

```
AlertDialog  alert=builder.create();
if(alert.isShowing()){
    alert.dismiss();
}
else{
    alert.show();

}
```

with this

```
if(isactive){
    isactive = false;
    builder.dismiss();
}
else{
    AlertDialog  alert=builder.create();
    isactive = true;
    alert.show();
}
```